# Transform and Pivot in Access to SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm moving Access DB to SQL Server 2012. I came across Transform and Pivot after reading a few things on the net. I'm posting here. How could I migrate the below query as a View if that is possible.

```
TRANSFORM First([TABLE1].EFE) AS FE

SELECT [TABLE1].COL1, First([TABLE1].EFE) AS [Total Of EFE]
FROM [TABLE1]
GROUP BY [TABLE1].COL1
PIVOT [TABLE1].COL3;
```

I appreciate your help I'm really new to Access functions.

Comment: Do you have a limited number of values for `[TABLE1].COL3`? If not, then you'll have to use dynamic sql and that can't be used in a view. Also, there is no real `FIRST()` function in SQL Server - if you edit your post with some sample data and the desired result, it would be easier to help.

Comment: There are 50,000 records in the table1 and for col3 there are 2 values for all records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing similar conversions and discovering that the "Group By" that is used in Access can be avoided in TSQL if your FROM is designed correctly. Because the PIVOT requires a whole table scan, unexpected things can happen (i.e. it will fail entirely if your FROM table has a TEXT column, even if that column is not a part of your query!)

I've had best results by omitting the Group By statement and instead using a subquery in the FROM statement. Additionally, I've used MAX instead of First, which may work if you provide some sample data.